# Single git repo setup tracking multiple locations on hard drive

Tags: wordpress, git, version-control, middleman

I'm very new to the world of git (done some svn in the past) and would like some advice on trying to accomplish the following.

My current workflow is that I setup the static html files using Middleman to get the base HTML structure and styles before porting over to a Wordpress template. These static files are located at `C:/git/project-name/HTMLTemplates`.

My wordpress setup uses Xampp so the theme files are kept in `C:/Xampp/wordpress/wp-content/themes/project-theme`.

What I would like to do is have a single git repo that tracks the changes of the two different locations (HTMLTemplates and project-theme)

Is this at all possible, or do I simply create two individual repos (eg: proect-static and project-wordpress)?

Comment: If you were using Linux or a Mac, you could probably do this sort of thing using symbolic links, and keep everything versioned under one folder in Git.  Not sure how you could do it in Windows though.  Is this something that you could do in SVN previously?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Cupcake. I haven't tried it in SVN either but from what I've read, it seems possible.

Comment: @Cupcake: Well, in SVN you could put both directories into one repo, and check out each directory in the appropriate location, because SVN has partial checkouts. That's not (easily) possible with git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no mechanism in git for this. Git assumes that all files that it manages (the "working copy") live in a single directory (and subdirectories); there is no support for managing two separate directories in in repo.

So you'll have to somehow keep everything in one directory, probably as subdirectories `HTMLTemplates` and `theme` or similar.

You could use two git repos, but I'd strongly advise against this. A single repo should contain a whole "project", i.e. everything needed to build one piece of software (excluding things like external libraries). If you split your project across two repositories, you cannot usefully branch and merge (because you'd have to do it in both repos simultaneously), you cannot easily check out old versions etc..

To solve your problem, I see a few possible solutions:

- Have some build / deployment script that copies everything to the right places. You probably alread have a script that invokes Middleman, and possibly tells Wordpress to refresh its cache, so you could add it there.
- Set up a symbolic link for the wordpress directory. On UNIX-like systems this is easy and commonly done. On Windows, you can create ["junction points"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point), which I believe work similarly.
- Configure Wordpress / Apache to read the directory directly from your git working copy. The path should be configurable.

I would prefer the first solution; this has the added advantage that it will decouple your development environment from the server configuration. This will make it easier if your setup later changes or your project needs to run in a different environment (development on a different machine, someone else also wants to work on your project, you want to deploy to a hosted server somewhere etc.).

*Note:* The problem is, I believe, that your are trying to use git as a deployment tool. While many people do this, git is not really suitable for this purpose. Deployment should usually be a separate step.

Comment: I did not know that Windows had such a thing as "junction points".  It's an interesting option, if it works well. As for Git not being suitable as a deployment tool, I'm not convinced of that yet, because like you say, a lot of people seem to be using it for that purpose.  In fact, services such as Heroku encourage you to use Git for deployment purposes, don't they?

Comment: Thanks @sleske! This is super helpful. I'm not using git for deployment purposes (I use FTP for that), I simply start a project in Middleman and then manually copy everything over to my local wordpress instance (need to better automate this).

So what I'd like to do is have;
1. C:/GIT/project-name/HTMLTemplates/ (middleman files)
2. C:/GIT/project-name/WP-Theme/theme-name/ (wordpress theme)

Path 2 links to local wordpress theme (C:/Xampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme-name)

Then Git tracks both folders under C:/GIT/project-name.

How can xampp wordpress know about theme in Path 2?

Comment: @TomGillard: As I wrote in my answer: Either use junction points to make `C:/Xampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme-name` point to `C:/GIT/project-name/WP-Theme/theme-name`, or reconfigure WP, or write a script that copies the theme files to the WP directory. If you have a problem with a specific step, consider posting a new question about that.

Comment: For anybody interested/with the same issue I found the following article most helpful regarding Junction Points (which @sleske mentioned in his answer)

http://windows7themes.net/how-to-create-junction-points-in-windows-7.html

Comment: @TomGillard: Hm, the article seems wrong to me. They claim that "can’t create junctions points in Windows 7 without some add-ons." However, you can, with `mklink`, available since Windows Vista.

Comment: @sleske, that's interesting. I was able to create a junction point from the steps in the article - I did have to download and install a little addon though. Will look into the mklink for future projects. Thanks again!